# map function iterate take a props value dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js . Here, I have one array of obj which is ,

```
let criterias = [{
      type: 'Low',
      noc: 6,
      data: this.props.lowData
    }, {
      type: 'Medium',
      noc: 7,
      data: this.props.MediumQuizData

    },
    {
      type: 'High',
      noc: 7,
      data: this.props.HighData
    }]
```

which I am using like this,

```
{criterias.map(criteria => (
          <LowLevelCriteria techData={this.state.technologies} data={criteria.data} type={criteria.type} noc={criteria.noc} handler={this.handler.bind(this)} />
        ))}
```

Now, In the `LoweverCriteria.js`,

```
{(this.props.data) && this.props.data.type.map((data, index) => (
          <LowRow technologies={this.state.technologies} onChange={this.onchange.bind(this)} index={index + 1} data={data} key={data.id} onAddRow={this.onaddRow.bind(this)} onRemoveRow={this.onRemoveRow.bind(this)}
            hasError={this.state.hasError}
          />
```

So, In this I want to use that props here like ,

```
this.props.data.{this.props.type}.map, so that type value is a dynamic. so  I am not understanding How to do this ? I tried with 

let type = this.props.type, and then using type , but no luck. so, can any one help me with this ?
```

Comment: `this.props.data[this.props.type].map`

Comment: check [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation), for more details.

Comment: ```[...(new Set(criterias.map(function(item) { return item.type })))].map()```